# MySQL Workbench Will not connect to localhost. "Database server instance is unknown"

Tags: mysql, error-handling, localhost, mysql-workbench

My MySQL Workbench is not connecting to my local host, and I cannot figure out why exactly it is reacting like this. It just started doing this one day, and randomly it will give me access although it says it is still "unknown", but I am tired of this and would like to fix it.

Since this website reqires that I have a "10" reputation to post images, I will have to describe it.

On the Startup/Shutdown tab in the administration page, it says:

The database server instance is unknown. --The "Start Server" button is faded out so that I cannot click it.

Startup Message Log
2013-07-11 08:57:51 - Workbench will use cmd shell commands to start/stop this instance

2013-07-11 08:57:51 - Status check of service 'MySQL' returned error: Not found

2013-07-11 08:57:51 - Status check of service 'MySQL' returned error: Not found

2013-07-11 09:00:55 - Status check of service 'MySQL' returned error: Not found

2013-07-11 09:00:55 - Status check of service 'MySQL' returned error: Not found

2013-07-11 09:02:01 - Status check of service 'MySQL' returned error: Not found

Then on the server status tab in the administration page, it says:

Name: mysqld@localhost
host: localhost
server:unknown
status: unknown

Connection
There is no connection to the MySQL server. This functionality requires an established connection to a running MySQL server to work.

If anyone can help out, that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: I have found a temporary solution, but when I go to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\Bin and double click on mysqld, I am able to start my server, but the start/stop page on the administration tab still says "unknown"

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on my Windows 8.1 machine and it turned out to be problems with the file permissions.

To repair it I went into the folder at "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6" and right clicked on the "data" folder and selected properties. Clicked the security tab and clicked edit. From there click the ADD button then the ADVANCED button and finally the FIND NOW button. In mine I added users, administrators, and "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES". I granted full control to the users that were already listed for the data folder and the users, administrators, and ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES.

After the permissions were repaired I opened a command prompt as administrator and changed to the "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin" directory `cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"`. From there you can execute `mysqld --install` which installs the MySQL service.

More information about installing the mysql service on windows can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-service.html

[edit] Please note that if you are using a different version of MySQL than the path to the MySQL data directory and bin directory may be different on your windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it: the service with the name `MySQL` cannot be found. So probably your MySQL service has a different name? Do you have a service at all? Starting mysql manually from the bin folder is just that: manual. There is no service involved, hence WB cannot manipulate the run state.

When you install MySQL with the MySQL installer you have everything in place within a couple minutes and it works right from the start.

So first check if you have a service running for your MySQL server and stop starting it manually. If there's a service take its name and enter it in the **Windows Service Name** field of the configuration manager:

[image]

**Note that MySQL Workbench can manage your server only if it is installed as a Windows service.**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Windows 8.1, and I solved it updating my workbench to Version6 with "mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.16.0.msi" from the official page of mysql

Answer (score 0):

I have found reinstalling all MySQL products a better alternative, because some of the solutions on the internet will make another instance of your mysql server along with mysql56, which might mess things up for a beginner.

Remember to keep database files and configuration undeleted during the reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem on MAC.
Please ensure you have installed mysql and its running. Because installing only workbench app, will not install mysql service. First install mysql and run the service.

In my case, I tried with brew

- `brew install mysql` // installing mysql
- `brew services restart mysql` // restart service after installing
- `mysql --version`  // check version